# TypeError python cupy

Tags: python, cupy

I'm trying to use cupy to speed up numerical integration. But I ran into the following problem, which is illustrated by the code below. Let the function for integration be given by its values in integer coordinates. In the example, this function is equal to 1 everywhere. It is expected to get 25 in the output, but the code breaks with the following error.
`TypeError: Implicit conversion to a NumPy array is not allowed. Please use` .get() `to construct a NumPy array explicitly.`

code:

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

temp_ar = np.ones(( 5, 5))

def F(x, y):
    return temp_ar[x, y] 


def num_integ_cp ():
    global N, M
    x, y = cp.meshgrid(cp.arange(0, 4), cp.arange( 0, 4))
    return cp.sum(F( x, y) + F(x+1, y) + F( x, y+1) + F(x+1, y+1)) / 4

outt = num_integ_cp()
print(outt)
```

I assume that the error is in calling the f function F because it can only accept (int, int)

Answer (score 2):

you can't mix together numpy and cupy, as cupy works on the GPU and numpy on CPU. To make your code work, just switch the "np.ones((5,5))" to "cp.ones((5,5))"